# Command window for java?

Tags: java, matlab

Is there a way to just run individual java commands without having to create a file? Kind of like the matlab command window, where you can just type one line and it'll run.

Comment: No. There is a [REPL coming to Java 9](https://www.jclarity.com/2015/04/15/java-9-repl-getting-started-guide/). Until then; Scala has a REPL...

Comment: That's called a REPL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Comment: You *could* run java commands *from* MATLAB and this works.

Comment: Do you accept the answers given? are they useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Currently**
No. 
Java is not a terminal programming language like matlab and python.

To run java applications, the commands must be compiled

When you compile, the java compiler turns the code into a class file. The class file contains "instructions" for the computer which is the application.

To clarify, Java 9 has `JShell`, which is a REPL for java. You can find the early access [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/).

Comment: Not true, there is a REPL in Java 9.

Comment: It's perfectly usable!

Comment: can I get a download link for a jdk\ for REPL?

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.jclarity.com/2015/04/15/java-9-repl-getting-started-guide/).

Comment: ah. a beta build. Possibly not stable. I myself wouldn't call that usable. But don't get me wrong, I find it interesting that REPL exists and can't wait to use it.

when a stable release is urm, released

Comment: Yes, Java 9 is EA. But your answer is still completely wrong, no? For example "_To run java applications, the commands must be compiled, and for that, they need to be in a file_" - this is false because 1) there is a Java REPL, 2) there is a Scala REPL, which will happily run Java code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - edited, better now? My answer is correct for the time being. I assume most users would rather use a released stable version, and not have to deal with weekly updates.

Comment: I would suggest that if a user is just looking to play around with Java on the command line then it matters very little if they're using the EA or a release version.

Comment: I see what you mean, My mistake. I updated the answer accordingly (I think)

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is something like this

https://blogs.oracle.com/java/jshell-and-repl-in-java-9

Sadly it isn't available until java 9, so in its current state it might not be production ready

try is here https://jdk9.java.net/download/

this shows you how to get it going

http://www.journaldev.com/9879/java9-install-and-repl-jshell-tutorial

Comment: Java 9 is available now. I doubt the OP is going to be using this is production, EA is fine for development and playing around.

Comment: @BoristheSpider fair point, I edit to say it isn't production ready then.